# aop:aspectj-autoproxy has worked bad at applicationContext

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm a beginner in spring,I have a problem with using **aop:aspectj-autoproxy** at applicationContext.It has confused me.
There is directory image:
[directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jaSUX.png)
The test codes is very simple,**I have omited 'import' statement**

#### applicationContext.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="schema2.*" />
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />

</beans>
```

---

#### Logger.java:

```java
@Aspect
@Component
public class Logger{
    @Before("execution(* schema2.manager.*(..))")
    public void before(JoinPoint joinPoint){
        System.out.println("The Method: " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
    }
}
```

#### BookShopDao.java:

```java
public interface BookShopDao{
    int findBookPriceByIsbn(String isbn);
    void updateBookStock(String isbn) throws RuntimeException;
    void updateUserAccount(String username, int price);
}
```

#### BookShopDaoImpl.java:

```java
@Repository("bookShopDao")
public class BookShopDaoImpl implements BookShopDao{
    @Override
    public int findBookPriceByIsbn(String isbn) {
        return 0;
    }
    @Override
    public void updateBookStock(String isbn) throws RuntimeException {
    }
    @Override
    public void updateUserAccount(String username, int price) {
    }
}
```

#### BookShopService.java:

```java
public interface BookShopService {
    void purchase(String book_isbn, String user_name);
}
```

#### BookShopServiceImpl.java:

```java
@Service("bookShopService")
public class BookShopServiceImpl implements BookShopService{
    @Override
    public void purchase(String book_isbn, String user_name) {
    }
}
```

#### Start.java

```java
public class Start {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
        BookShopService server = (BookShopService) context.getBean("bookShopService");
        server.purchase("123", "John");
    }
}
```

## problem:

```java
 Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'bookShopDao' defined in file [C:\Users\qiang\Desktop\spring\spring2\out\production\spring2\schema2\manager\BookShopDaoImpl.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: warning no match for this type name: schema2.manager [Xlint:invalidAbsoluteTypeName]
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'bookShopDao' defined in file [C:\Users\qiang\Desktop\spring\spring2\out\production\spring2\schema2\manager\BookShopDaoImpl.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: warning no match for this type name: schema2.manager [Xlint:invalidAbsoluteTypeName]
```

But if I delete

> aop:aspectj-autoproxy

which at applicationContext.xml,it become no problem,and it have losed @before logging

Answer (score 0):

I've found answer,I haven't checked carefull...

> @Before("execution(* schema2.manager.*(..))") should be changed to @Before("execution(* schema.manager*.*(..))")

And my project lib has been imported 'aspectj/lib' that whole directory, I also dont't konw why it cause the problem,it's weird.